# How to optimize fetching data from osmnx? Checking if a point lies on a road

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx

There are about 100,000 points with geometry information in the form of a csv file. The points are spatially distributed across the world in various different countries.

Trying to check if the points lie on a road or not.

The current approach is too slow for a huge number of points, is there a way to optimize programmatically (only have the country name) so we can fetch road networks of larger regions and then use the cache so it doesn't hit the API for each of the points points.

Using osmnx to get the graphs from a specific point and converting it into a GeoDataFrames

I am currently sldo using a custom filter to get specific road networks and have set the distance to 100 meters around a point.

```py
def check_point(longitude,latitude): 
    try: 
        point_geom = Point(longitude,latitude) 

        graph = ox.graph_from_point((latitude,longitude), dist=100) 
        gdf_roads = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=False, edges=True) 

        buffered_point = point_geom.buffer(0.00008) 
        intersects = gdf_roads.intersects(buffered_point) 
         
        return intersects.any()

    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)

return False
```

Comment: Two quick thoughts here. 1) your major inefficiency is creating one graph for each point you want to search. Without any knowledge of the spatial distribution of your points it's hard to guess how to optimize, but it'd be a lot more efficient if you cluster your points into reasonably sized areas (like metro areas) and then just download 1 graph for each such area and then perform your intersection. 2) it'd secondarily be more efficient to take the unary union of your area's roads' geometries and check if that intersects with whichever points in that area.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, sadly the data points are present in multiple different areas (many countries across the world so the spatial distribution is quite vast)

Comment: So for example,  If I am able to sample one row in a relatively good cluster size and download the graph road networks for that area, when requesting the graph again for points near it, will it automatically use cache ? Do I have to set the cache only mode for that?  Thanks!

Comment: OSMnx caches HTTP responses. It'll only retrieve from the cache if you make the exact same HTTP request again.